iterm2 tmux integration jumps to beginning of line when switching windows
I am using tmux integration for iterm2 (macos client sshing to linux server), and I am encountering an annoying behavior where the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line every time I switch tmux panes. This means that if I've typed half of a command, switch to a different pane and switch back, I am at the beginning of the line rather than the end (where I usually want to be in order to finish typing the command).
I haven't found whether there is a setting to toggle this behavior.

What OS? Is the behavior the same if you run this on a different computer? Have you looked elsewhere online for others who might have had the same issue?

This is macos client to a linux server

Please put that info in the question body to help make it clearer.

added the clarification

Seems like adding set -g focus-events off to ~/.tmux.conf in the linux host fixed the issue.
